# Bold text in plain text e-mail?

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to bold some text when sending a plain text email via PHP? Saw something that you could use

```
*bold*
```

But it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Can't be done, boss. It's called "plain" text for a reason.

Comment: Plain text means plain text - no formatting. Whether the email client renders `*text*` bold or not is not under your control.

Comment: plain text can't be formatted

Comment: Don't listen to the other guys, plain text certainly DOES have bold, its just that they call it upper case.

Comment: Uppercase is LIKE SCREAMING AT THE TOP OF YOUR LUNGS vs bold which is **emphasizing a point** :)

Comment: You  do something like this if the definition of "plain text" du jour includes Unicode (that was  done with HTML or markdown, any more than  or  or ). But that's cheating.

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed as it is very clear for someone who knows how emails are working.

Comment: @TextGeek "cheating" demonstrated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569635/540955

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope. Plain text is plain text.

You maybe thinking of a [framework](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (which is what stackoverflow uses) to compile something like ** text ** into:

```
<strong>text</strong>
```

Like so: **text**. But the result would have to be HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get this working is if your email client supports this type of format since plain text is just... well, text. You can even write in BBcode if your email client supports it. Of course that if you write something for someone using this "super client", the receiver will only be able to see the formatting if they also have the client installed.