# How to console.log() , any letter but in bold?

Tags: javascript, unicode, fonts

There are certain ways to print letters in javascript using unicode
FOr example

`console.log(`\u0062`)` yields a b , so its the same as putting `console.log(b)`

But now, I do know there are certains way to console.log bold letters, for example

```
console.log('')
```

prints a bold word in the console.

But what would be a function for example to print in bold?

THis is my idea

```
const printBold = (word: string) => {
  //splits the string, gets every letter, and replaces with the bold unicode equivalent
}
```

But... im unable to find a unicode equivalent for bold letters, or a way to create a function that logs in bold.

Maybe I can do something like

```
const map = {
 "a": "bold_a",
 "b": ''
}
```

And feed the converter with that data, but... where do I get the bold unicodes or characters from?
THe only ones I could find, i copied them from this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569635/9010895

Comment: **Danger**: Those are not bold **letters**, they are mathematic symbols designed for writing equations. Trying to use them as bold letters will play havock with screen readers and search engines.

Comment: You'd look at a Unicode table that contains these characters: https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/. But as noted above, **they're not equivalent to the word "bold"**, they have as much in common as if you wrote ボルド.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current approach is seriously flawed. Those are not bold letters, they are [mathematic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) designed for writing equations. Trying to use them as bold letters will play havock with screen readers.

The console *does* have [features for formatting text](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/format-style/#style-console-messages) which you should use instead.

You can use a format specifier:

```js
const bold = "font-weight: bold";
const normal = "font-weight: normal";
console.log("A string with a %cbold%c word", bold, normal);
```

Or an ANSI escape sequence