# Python format mail body in bold by taking user input

Tags: python, email, formatting, office365

I want to take input parameters from user and then use that in sentences in mail body,then i want some words(this will be user input) in the sentences to be bold.So when i send that mail to gmail/outlook those words should appear in bold

```py
import smtplib
BOLD='\033[1m'
END='\033[1;m'
sender ='username@domain.com'
receiver=['username@domain.com']

title=raw_input("enter title:")
subject="Test"

body="HI All\n\nThe title entered is:{0} {1} {2}".format(BOLD,title,END)

message="Subject:{0}\n\n{1}".format(subject,body)

try:
  smtpobj=smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
  smtpObj.sendmail(sender,receivers,message)
  print "Mail sent"
except SMTPException:
  print "Error: Failed to send"
```

Now after doing this, when you open outlook and check mail, i want that **title(must be user input)** to be in bold,but it prints the **BOLD code** in the mail body rather than printing that title in bold

Note- the variable that we need to make bold should be input from user i.e it will be dynamic and not hardcoded..so i guess we can't do using html

Answer (score 0):

Your email is sent as plain text, which you cannot make bold. If you want to change your plain text to HTML you can easily make it bold.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954662/bold-text-in-plain-text-e-mail).

You might also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python), where they use your library to send HTML.